# Adding a Usercontrol with a transparent Background to a Window

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, user-controls

I have created a UserControl with some rounded edged Border as first real element. The actuall Background is transparent.

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QP_WPF" x:Class="GUI_WPF_Interior"
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
         xmlns:themes="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Themes;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
mc:Ignorable="d" 
            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         d:DesignWidth="600
" Background="transparent">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ColorsAndBrushes.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ControlTemplates.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Border  Margin="10" Background="{StaticResource BG_GradientBrush_2}" CornerRadius="12,12,12,12">
....
```

(the Margin is only to provide a better visual for the problem)

Now I want to display this UserControl in a window. But the area that is used by the margin and the rounded edges stays white.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:qp="clr-namespace:QP_WPF;assembly=QP_WPF"
Title="MainWindow" Height="680" Width="600"
WindowStyle="None"    
AllowsTransparency="True"
MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <qp:GUI_WPF_Interior x:Name="GUIInterior" Background="Transparent"/>
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

What do I need to doe so that the Window only displays my UserControls parts that are not transparent?

Comment: I know there are quit a few questions like this, but non of the ones i found had a accepted answer or even one with a good amount of up-votes

Comment: Do you mean that your Border element remains white? What do you have in your BG_GradientBrush_2 style?

Comment: some different Gray/white Shades

Comment: Delete the Background=transparent from your UserControl and provide only a background color to your border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add also background=transparent to the window besides AllowTransparency